# Keycloak error: Cannot exchange code for grant in bearer-only mode

Tags: keycloak

Using `keycloak-connect` with the following configuration:

```
{
  "realm": "example",
  "auth-server-url": "http://localhost:8080/auth/",
  "ssl-required": "external",
  "resource": "example",
  "verify-token-audience": true,
  "credentials": {
    "secret": "<hidden>"
  },
  "use-resource-role-mappings": true,
  "confidential-port": 0
}
```

Post login, I'm getting the following error:

```
Cannot exchange code for grant in bearer-only mode.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share the config of your client in Keycloak (screenshot)?

Comment: Had a bug somewhere else. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are using Keycloak client, which has `Access type: bearer-only`. 'Bearer-only' clients are web services that never initiate a login. So any login attempt/code exchange is refused by the Keycloak in this case as you see.

Comment: But this is the crazy thing here. My client Access Type is `confidential` :D

Comment: No it's not a crazy. I don't see any `clientId` in your keycloak-connect configuration, so I guess some default client id is used, which is bearer-only apparently.

Comment: I'm following the tutorial from https://medium.com/theoptimaltechnologist/what-is-keycloak-how-to-use-it-an-example-with-nodejs-part-2-46b562e2b46c, where it says to copy the "Keycloak OIDC JSON" installation. The above JSON is exactly what it produces.

Comment: I even disabled all auto-generate clients. The only client I have has Access Type set to `confidential`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a bug somewhere else. When creating an `express-session`'s `MemoryStore` instance, I forgot the word `new` :)